# Upstart console output not working

Tags: logging, console, upstart

I used Upstart's provided example for [console output](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#console-output).

**/etc/init/test.conf**

```
console output

pre-start script

  # Perform whatever checks you like here (maybe checking
  # '/etc/default/foo' to see if the service is enabled # or not).
  #
  # if there are no problems detected, simply "exit 0", else do
  # something like this...

  # display an error message to stderr *on the console* and also write
  # the same message to the system log.
  logger -is -t "$UPSTART_JOB" "ERROR: foo!"

  # tell Upstart not to start the main process for the job.
  exit 1
end script

# this service doesn't do much :-)
exec sleep 999
```

And then as root

```
$ initctl start test
initctl: Job failed to start
```

The message is present in `/var/log/syslog`, but the message was not present in the console.

```
Jul 23 07:42:19 paul test[26595]: ERROR: foo!
```

---

How can I log errors to the console?

This is Ubuntu 14.04,

```
$ initctl version
init (upstart 1.12.1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`console output` writes to `/dev/console`, which, by default, is the system virtual logging device: it's not going to write to your personal console (e.g. `/dev/tty0`).

You can actually test the difference in behavior if you attempt to write directly to these virtual devices:

```
sudo echo test >> /dev/console     # Won't work
sudo su; echo test >> /dev/console # Works but nothing prints
sudo echo test >> /dev/tty0        # Works and prints
```

For more on the differences between the different virtual console devices, see [this Unix StackExchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60641/linux-difference-between-dev-console-dev-tty-and-dev-tty0).

If you really want, you can change what `/dev/console` points to by modifying your boot configuration:

```
# /etc/default/grub

# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8"
```

...but if I were you, I'd just use the `console log` stanza instead of `console output` and then tail the generated file.

Comment: So when the docs say `display an error message to stderr *on the console*`, they mean `display an error message to stderr *on the sys admin's console*`? I'm not sure what the utility of that would be.

Comment: It's going to be to whatever console to which you've set `/dev/console`, which may or may not be the sys admin's console, but that's a very reasonable default: there are security implications to logging system processes in the open.